# Optimizar consulta laravel

Tags: laravel, bucle-for, optimización, laravel-excel, querybuilder

¿Es posible optimizar una consulta que contiene un sum() dentro de un for anidado?. Actualmente el servidor tarda cerca de un minuto en ejecutar el script (La BD tiene más de 100 mil registros)

La idea es recorrer ciertas celdas de un archivo excel y calcular el valor que corresponde a cada celda. Como lo hago actualmente funciona pero tarda demasiado:

```
$obtenerFilas = DB::table('prestaciones' . strtolower($request->selectSerie . $request->selectPeriodo))->where('pre_rem', $remSeleccionado)->where('pre_periodo', $request->selectPeriodo)->get();

foreach ($obtenerFilas as $filas) {
            for ($i=$filas->pre_columna_inicial+1; $i <= $filas->pre_columna_final+1; $i++) {
                    if ($i <= 9) 
                        $columna = 'col0' . $i;
                    else
                        $columna = 'col' . $i;
                    $CalcularValor = DB::table('serie' . $request->selectSerie . $request->selectPeriodo)
                    ->where('mes', '>=', $request->selectMesInicial)
                    ->where('mes', '<=', $request->selectMesFinal)
                    ->where('codigoPrestacion', $filas->pre_codigo)
                    ->whereRaw($ConsultaSQL)
                    ->sum($columna);
                    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i, $filas->pre_fila, $CalcularValor);
                }
            }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si la BD es SQL usa el método [`toSQL()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) para obtener la consulta, y en una sesión en la BD obtén un `EXPLAIN` para dicha consulta.

Comment: ¿Eso es válido si la consulta varía según lo ingresado por el usuario? Por ahora estoy intentando usar una vista para precargar los datos de una sola vez, pero no sé si me resultará

Comment: Tal y como dice Sal, mira la consulta generada, pero ->sum() no tengo claro si lo hará SQL o recuperará los datos y sumará desde PHP.
Yo probaría `->selectRaw("SUM($columna) AS total")->first()`, y luego $CalcularValor->total, para estar seguro que suma la BdD